# PHP If and <img> not displaying image

Tags: php, wordpress

When I write:

```
<?php if ( 1==1 ) : ?>
 Working
<?php endif ?>
```

It's working I mean it's displaying "Working" but when I write:

```
<?php if ( 1==1 ) : ?>
        <img class="up" src="/wp-content/themes/template/img/up.png">
<?php endif ?>
```

It's not displaying anything and if I put:

```
<img class="up" src="/wp-content/themes/template/img/up.png">
```

Outside IF statement It's displaying that image. Please help!

Comment: can not reproduce. https://3v4l.org/Shrcg

Comment: @hanshenrik What do You mean?

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. When testing the snippet you've provided here, the HTML img tag is correctly output as you would expect. There's nothing here to suggest that something should be wrong. If you really are experiencing issues and you're using the exact same code you've shown us here, then the problem has to be in the surrounding code/markup, which you haven't shown us. It's possible that the if statement isn't in the correct place and that it's causing the image not to render. We can only speculate.

Comment: is the image in the right location? /wp-content/themes/template/img/up.png? can you use full path from the url?

Comment: Off-topic: Cannot reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some php versions don´t support ":" estructure. Try this instead:

```
<?php if ( 1==1 ) { ?>
        <img class="up" src="/wp-content/themes/template/img/up.png">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The first part of the question seems to indicate that this couldn't be the problem.